# How to show the widget same like an Alarm widget (Clock APP)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification, ios-app-extension

I need to do the app same as Clock Alarm functionality. Once we set the Alarm for some time like 3.15PM (Even app is not in running state) It shows in

1. Today Notification screen - [image: Today Screen]

   we can do this(your alarm......) using APP Extension (using User defaults), right?

   2. As Pop up screen [image: Phone Popup]
   3. Alarm Pop Up in lock screen - [image: Alarm Pop up]

**My Question** -

a. How can we achieve both 2 and 3, Is this a same APP Extension concept?

b. In First - I believe they used User defaults, Can we do the API access in APP Extension like checking web service periodically?

Please suggest solution/idea to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the same thing as an app extension or widget. I also, don't believe its possible to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh Ok Thanks! I too believe it's not possible, but how can Clock app achieve this? I hope some other way is there?

Comment: The reason the clock app can do this, is due to it being an Apple app - they would have used private APIs that us developers do not have access to.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. 

Is there any other approach to show some widget on "App not running state"?
And can we do web service access in App extension?

Comment: Widgets should have zero knowledge about a host app's running state. They (Widgets) are independent of an app. Yes, you will be able to do REST requests on widgets.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Tander